# MySQL: how to get average time spent by all users and single user

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, group-by

I have two tables every time when user comes I create new New user record table is following

```
tbl_users:

---------------------------------------
id     | name     | created_at
---------------------------------------
1      | Danny    | 2020-04-20 12:47:37
```

and another table where they send messages

```
tbl_messages:
-------------------------------------------
id    | user_id   | message    | created_at
-------------------------------------------
1     | 1         | test mesh  | 2019-04-20 12:47:37
```

from user record created to last message created will be assumed as time spent by user. I am looking for a MySQL query where I can print single time spent and average time spent by all users? is it possible with MYSQL?

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: I want to return in minutes like average user spent 10 min or 20 min. thank you

Comment: That's the rule. Please add the exact expected result, according to your example data.

Comment: The parts of this are faqs. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join and aggregate twice:

```
select avg(max_diff) avg_diff_seconds
from (
    select max(timestampdiff(second, u.created_at, m.created_at)) max_diff
    from users u
    inner join messages m on m.user_id = u.id
    group by u.id, u.created_at
) t
```

The subquery computes the greatest difference between each user's creation time and the timestamp of their messages - this actually gives you the difference between the creation time and their latest message. Then, the outer query computes the average.

Comment: thank you, will it print avg time spent by all users? why you query ends with ) t?

Comment: @danny: yes that’s the average for all users (provided that they have at least one message). `t` is an alias for the subquery, that’s a requirement in MySQL and most other databases.

Comment: if would like to return specific user I can add select avg(max_diff) avg_diff_seconds
from (
    select max(timestampdiff(second, u.created_at, m.created_at)) max_diff
    from users u
    inner join messages m on m.user_id = u.id where u.id =1
    group by u.id, u.created_at
) t

Comment: @danny: if you want this just for one user, no need for the outer query. Just: `select max(timestampdiff(second, u.created_at, m.created_at)) max_diff
    from users u
    inner join messages m on m.user_id = u.id where u.id = 1
    group by u.id, u.created_at`